# Compare two adjacent values with another two adjacent values

Tags: vba, excel, compare

I'm fairly new to macro programming and having hard time in writing one where I could compare two adjacent cell value with other two adjacent values.

What I wanna achieve is I have some values in Column A and Column B, the value in Column A correspondence to column B e.g. Column A holds Employee ID and Column B the name of the Employee. Same data I have in Column C and D but not all records exist in C and D as compared to in A and B.

I'm looking for a macro code help where it first Compares column A first row against column C all rows if the match is found then compare its corresponding column B value against the column D value(same row). If column B and D does not match then paste the value of B and D in column E and F

[image: Table]

Comment: Please post a small sample of the table structure and desired output for this sample. It may be easily achievable using SQL against the worksheet.

Comment: have already uploaded a table image, pls help

Answer (score 0):

Let's say this is a model of your table, whee id1, id2, name1 and name2 are the column headers:

```
   id1    Name1    id2    Name2     
   101    John     502      Tom
```

You can do something like this. Add a reference to "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1" first. Then try this macro. I assumed your sheet name is "Sheet1", if not you can change it.

```
 Sub GetUnmatchedRecords()

 Dim sQuery As String, sFileName  as String
 Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
 Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

 sFileName = ThisWorkbook.FullName
 sConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=""" & _
   sFileName & """;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX = 1"""

 Conn.Open sConnection 

 sQuery = "SELECT id1,name1 From [Sheet1$] where id1+name1 not in (SELECT id2+name2 from [Sheet1$])"
 rs.Open sQuery , Conn

 Sheet1.Range("E2").CopyFromRecordset rs
 rs.Close
 conn.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: your code throws error as "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" :(

Comment: are id1 and id2 numeric fields? Can you change them to 'text' type? This is the issue. Try: "SELECT id1,name1 From [Sheet1$] where str(id1)+name1 not in (SELECT str(id2)+name2 from [Sheet1$])"

Comment: OK, they are numeric, just saw the data you posted. Change the numeric columns from General to Text or alternatively try the SQL statement above.